# Fetch Rails join model records based on condition in joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many, scopes

I'm wondering if there's a "proper" Rails (3.1) way to do this without just using a finder SQL.

I have an STI hierarchy:

```
class Party
class Person < Party
class Organisation < Party
```

Related parties are joined via a party_relationships table and model, with foreign keys party_id and related_party_id

I want to be able to do is this:

```
class Party
  # Should return all party_relationships where the related_party is a Person
  has_many :person_relationships

  # Should return all party_relationships where the related_party is an Organisation
  has_many :organisation_relationships
end
```

What's the best way of doing this in Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. This works, and I have to say that I'm *very* impressed with the way the scopes and relationships work:

```
class Party
  has_many :party_relationships, foreign_key: :party_id
end

class PartyRelationship
  belongs_to :related_party, :class_name => 'Party'
  scope :to_organisations, :joins => :related_party, :conditions => {:parties => {:type => 'Organisation' } }
end
```

Now if I have a party...

```
@party.party_relationships                   # <- returns all relationships
@party.party_relationships.to_organisations  # <- Only those where related_party is an organisation
```

What I *really* like about this is that if I'd used :finder_sql on a has_many then the SQL would be in the Party class. This way keeps things properly encapsulated so that a Party doesn't have to know *how* the scope is implemented. Neat.